# Duplicated Eav attribute in Product Edit form

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, eav-attributes

I want to add a new attribute to the product edit form using the **UI components**, so I created a `product_form.xml` file in my module, and added the attribute with the code below:

```xml
<field name="activate_meta_robots" sortOrder="170" formElement="checkbox">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">product</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <dataType>boolean</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Activate Meta Robots</label>
        <scopeLabel>[STORE VIEW]</scopeLabel>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <checkbox>
            <settings>
                <valueMap>
                    <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                    <map name="true" xsi:type="number">1</map>
                </valueMap>
                <prefer>toggle</prefer>
            </settings>
        </checkbox>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

Then, I had to create also the eav attribute in the database in order to save the attribute value. Thus, I created a Data Patch file and added the following code:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    Product::ENTITY,
    'activate_meta_robots', [
        'type' => 'int',
        'label' => 'Activate Meta Robots',
        'input' => 'checkbox',
        'source' => Boolean::class,
        'sort_order' => 170,
        'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'group' => 'General Information',
    ]
);
```

But, when I access the Product Edit form, I see the attribute duplicated: one comes from the ui_component:

[image]

and the other is the one I add through the `addAttribute()` method:

[image]

I know that I could just remove the ui_component, but I need it. I tried to put `'visible' => false` in the `addAttribute()` method, but in this way the attribute from the ui_component doesn't save its value anymore.

Does anyone know a way to add the attribute created in the ui_component to the db in order to save its value without duplicating the attribute?

Comment: why you need the ui_component if the attribute is already showed from the eav attribute?

Comment: since from the ui-component I can use the switcherConfig to show/hide/disable other fields added through the eav attribute table.

Comment: Have you tried to customize 'activate_meta_robots' eav attribute js component to show/hide/disable other fields added through the eav attribute table?

Comment: Nope, could you give me some insights on this way?

Comment: I see that you know modifier, so simple you could modify meta for 'activate_meta_robots'  eav attribute with the logic assigned to the custom component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself. I publish here my solution in case anyone else experiences the same issue.

The idea is to hide the attributes rendered through the eav attribute table, to leave only the ones added with the Ui components.

To do that, you need to create a **Modifier Pool** (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/customize-modifier-class.html) and change, at runtime, the `formElement` attribute of the eav attribute to `hidden`.

I wrote a small function that you can use to automatically do that:

```
protected function setupAttributeForUiComponent(array $meta, array $attributeCodes) {
    foreach ($attributeCodes as $attributeCode) {
        // find attribute path
        $path = $this->arrayManager->findPath($attributeCode, $meta, null, 'children');
        // set the attribute as hidden to prevent attribute duplication
        $meta = $this->arrayManager->set("{$path}/arguments/data/config/formElement", $meta, 'hidden');
    }
    return $meta;
}
```

You can call this method inside the method `modifyMeta` of your Modifier Pool:

```
public function modifyMeta(array $meta) {
    $meta = parent::modifyMeta($meta);
    $this->setupAttributeForUiComponent($meta, ["activate_meta_robots"]);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How do you change the value of hidden eav attribute? Is it linked to your custom activate_meta_robots component?

Comment: It's an attribute that I found inside the meta of all the eav attributes.